# How do I locate python command line tools after installing to (non-root) user account?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, httpie

On my work server I run `sudo pip install httpie` which allows me to execute `http google.com`.

On my school server I run `pip install --user httpie`. When I attempt to use the utility, I get a `http: command not found` error. I know that the package is installed at

```
/home/grads/me/.local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/httpie
```

but I am not quite sure how to register the command line tool. My work server says the command is located in `/usr/bin/http` but I have not been able to locate a binary on my school server.

I did try something like `find / |& grep http` but there is way too many things to look at. I am assuming I just need to add something to my `PATH`, but the question is what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically they'll be installed to `~/.local/bin`.

Add that to your path:

`export PATH="$PATH":/home/grads/me/.local/bin`

And you should be able to run the command like you expect.

Comment: Awesome! I suppose I should have started my search from ~. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: limiting things is always a good idea, when you can ;) If this solves your problem don't forget to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Absolutely! Just waiting for the timer to let me hit the check mark. Appreciate the quick response.